# How to pass data to parent layout from database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass the user data from my database into **parent layout** (app.layouts). Purpose of that is, there is a column that stores **token** in my database. I want to pass that to **parent layout** in order to use that in metatag.

**How I will use it:**
`<meta name="access-token" content="{{$user->token}}"></meta>`

The problem is, I can't find out how to pass the user data into layouts.

Usually, when I would pass the data into views I would do:

```
$users = User::all();

return view('welcome')->with(['user' => $user]);
```

But the code returns to **view**, I need to pass to layout, not view. Technically, layout is a view too but I don't think that would work.

Are there any easier solutions of that problem? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use View::composer:

```
// Using class based composers...
View::composer(
    'profile', 'App\Http\View\Composers\ProfileComposer'
);

// Using Closure based composers...
View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
    //
});
```

see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers